# Association bonus isn't mentioned in help pages where it would be expected

Tags: feature-request, association-bonus

Perhaps it's not technically a privilege, but one would expect the [association bonus](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/what-is-the-association-bonus) (awarded at 200 rep) to be listed along with all the other awards mentioned on the [privileges help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: SO IS ANYONE GOING TO FIX IT? HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo?